# I am having a problem printing off the content of a column that in a file

Tags: python, csv

I have read a column from a CSV file that contains temperatures. They print off fine but there is the letter C after each number. I want to print off only the numbers from the column. I would appreciate any help I can get with that.

```
import csv


with open('Data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:

        print(line[1])
```

Comment: You should read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/, specifically the [part about slicing strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). But you should read all of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a character from a string using the `str.replace` method.

```py
import csv

with open('Data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line[1].replace("C", ""))  # Replaces "C" with ""
```